# Create Keyrock users for WStore and WMarket

Tags: fiware, keystone

I'd like to programmatically create user accounts from our own app/api and got to the point I can indeed add users to my local Keyrock (a fork of Keystone) instance. Unfortunately these users remain useless because they get automatically logged out the moment they are successfully logged in.

Can anyone let me know what are the minimum user account properties needed to successfully login a user to WStore?

TIA, Edoardo

Answer (score 0):

This question is the same than the one posted on https://ask.fiware.org/question/441/programmatically-create-keyrock-users-for-wstore-and-wmarket-etc/. Please, let's continue there.